# How to simulate click event with mock function in enzyme and Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have foo component I want to simulate button click with a mock function

```
 export default class Foo extends Component {
        btnClick() {
            console.log("hello...");
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h2>Hello</h2>
                    <button onClick={this.btnClick.bind(this)} id="btn">Click</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

My test code looks like following

```
 it("must call the mock method with button click", () => {

        const wrapper = mount(<Foo />);
        wrapper.instance().btnClick = jest.fn(() => {
            return 8;
        });

        wrapper.update();

        const btn = wrapper.find("#btn");
        btn.simulate("click");

        expect(wrapper.instance().btnClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

simulation of click event calls the components real method instead of calling the mock method.

I know it can be done by passing mock function as props to the `<Foo/>` component.

I want to know is there any other way to simulate click(**i.e private to the component**) with mock method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that you were rendering the component first and then trying to mock the function, by that time, you already created a bounded copy, the solution then is to mock directly into the prototype.

```
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {configure, mount} from 'enzyme'

configure({adapter: new Adapter()})

export default class Foo extends Component {
  btnClick() {
    console.log("hello...")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
        <button
            id="btn"
            onClick={this.btnClick.bind(this)}
        >
          Click
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

it("must call the mock method with button click", () => {
    let spy =  jest.spyOn(Foo.prototype, 'btnClick')
      .mockImplementation(() => 8)

    const wrapper = mount(<Foo/>)
    const btn = wrapper.find("#btn")
    btn.simulate("click")

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: This did not work ended with error "Cannot spy the undefined property because it is not a function; undefined given instead",

Comment: I think you have not given second parameters that is the method name as string to the spyOn

Comment: Yes, I missed the method's name, sorry.

Comment: I used the second parameter method's name 'btnClick' but that resulted in failure of test "Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.". The mock function has not been called

Comment: Yeah, I missed the fact that you were rendering the component and the bind(this) created a copy of that method, by the time that happens, it's not possible to mock it anymore. The solution is to mock the prototype of the method. Updated the answer with the solution.

Comment: Thanks, thats great !!! but why need  wrapper.update() if we have added the mock function to its prototype.

Comment: Yep, there's no need to call the updated there, I didn't sleep well today.

Comment: HI, I have a similar problem, i followed the answer above, but i get this error: `Expected mock function to have been called`. Any idea what is going on why i cannot successfully create a mock function despite using a spyOn?

Comment: @AlexandreBorela instance can't be used when it is a stateless component. How would you tackle this same problem if it is an SFC?

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Foo from "path/Foo"

describe("Executes a handler function", () => {
  it("must call the mock method with button click", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
    const button = wrapper.find("button");
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    instance.btnClick = jest.fn(instance.btnClick);

    button.simulate("click");
    expect(instance.btnClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?